# What does hasNext() in a While do?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to read data from a .txt file. I've implemented a Scanner object 'in' `Scanner in=new Scanner("file.txt");` and then down the code a while loop to traverse through the content of the file.There are multiple rows of data in the file and in each row there are three strings (security number ,First name ,Last name : 01 Thomas Anderson)

```
while(in.hasNext()){
    String ss = in.next();
    String FName=in.next();
    String LName=in.next();
    
    System.out.printf("SSN: %s, FirstName: %s, LastName: %s \n",ss,FName,LName);
    }
```

So, what does the hasNext() method do? Does it look for end of the row or for the last row in the file or.... ?

Please elaborate on the working of the above snippet (mentioning the next() method too).

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the `Scanner.hasNext()` method in the API Javadoc? Because if you don't and your first reaction to seeing a method is asking here what it means, you are going to need a lot of questions.... If you have, please be more specific about what you do not understand.

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc? Were there any parts what we're unclear

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend looking at the Javadoc, but I'll explain it for you as simple as I can.

Basically, the hasNext() method returns `true` if the given document contains another string. Hence why the snippet will loop if said document **has** another string. Once there are no more Strings in the entire document, hasNext() returns`false`.

Here's an example of the next() method:
 `String myString = myScanner.next();`
This makes myString equal to the next string in the given document.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc says:

> ***hasNext***
>   public boolean hasNext()
>
> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This
>   method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not
>   advance past any input.
>
> ***next***
>   public String next()
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

To read all your file rows you'll have to check if there are tokens every line. Then you call 3 times the next method since you know there will be 3 tokens per line:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FLoader {

    public void load(String path) {
        Scanner in = null;

        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File(path));
            while (in.hasNext()) {  
                String ss = in.next();
                String FName = in.next();
                String LName = in.next();

                System.out.printf("SSN: %s, FirstName: %s, LastName: %s \n", ss, FName, LName);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Loading file failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```